# C++ not executing code when casting template pointer to char pointer

Tags: c++, cygwin

Cygwin 3.2.0
cmake 3.

Hello, I am new to c++ (just started yesterday) so I am not totally familiar with pointers. From what I understand, a pointer is just a location in memory of the first index of something with the compiler automatically scaling the pointer address on incrementation to whatever it was pointed to. From the below code and output, is this a bug in the Cywgin compiler or am I using pointers wrong? (There are no try/catch statements other than the ones shown below to catch exceptions).

The method `_put` is called from the method `write` with the class `V` being the same as the write generic. In the code below I am trying to execute `_put<short>(2)`. I am expecting the program to either throw an exception or print `"From DLL\nWorking from DLL"` and returning `1`. In this case neither is occurring leading me confused on why the second part of the put method code wasn't executed with no error to figure out what had happened.

```
//Code buried in a shared library (.dll)
//Trial 1 Code
template<class V>
void _put(long long index, V v){
    std::cout << std::endl << "From DLL";
    //void* t = (void*) v; //Works
    char* t = (char*) v; //Fails
    std::cout << std::endl << "Working from DLL?" << t;
}

//Code buried in a shared library (.dll)
//Trial 2 Code
template<class V>
void _put(long long index, V v){
    std::cout << std::endl << "From DLL";
    void* t = (void*) v; //Works
    //char* t = (char*) v; //Fails
    std::cout << std::endl << "Working from DLL?" << t;
}
```

```
//Exe code using the shared library
int main() {
    std::cout << "From Exe";
    try {
        Memory m(2000);
        m.write<short>(2);
        std::cout << m.get<char>() << "Test";
        return 1;
    }catch(const std::exception& ex){
        std::cerr << "Error : " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Output from trial 1 code:

```
From Exe 
From DLL
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Output from trial 2 code:

```
From Exe
From DLL
Working from DLL?0x2 Test
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What do you mean "fails"? The code is full of errors that make it not compilable, and fixing it to see what is going on would require to guess what you want to do.

Comment: @vonbrand. Code threw new errors on compilation and compiled just fine. In fact it partially executed

Comment: @JaMiT If you notice in the main method I have it return 1. In the first trial it is returning 0 and its also not print the last half of the _put method ("The working from DLL" etc). I am expecting either an exception to be thrown or the code to return 1 and print the expected lines. Because it did not do either I figured it was a bug. I am extremly new to c++ so maybe errors happen without any exception being thrown that I dont know about

Comment: My bad, fixed the question to hopefully show my intentions easier.

Comment: Your [mre] is missing a definition of `Memory::write()`. Hmm... also the destructor of `Memory` could be relevant, as throwing and exception while unwinding the stack for another exception causes immediate program termination. So maybe a trimmed down, yet complete definition of `Memory`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do this:

```
char* t = (char*) v;
std::cout << std::endl << "Working from DLL?" << t;
```

Then `v` needs to be pointing to a valid (C-style) string, and, most probably, it isn't.

If you intended to print out `t` as a raw address then you can do:

```
std::cout << std::endl << "Working from DLL?" << (void *) t;
```

Comment: So V HAS to be a valid string for the pointer to work?, that would explain why its failing. Is there any way to get the raw address and iterate the length of v in char (bytes)?

Comment: Yes it does.  I'm not sure I understand your second question, but untyped data does not carry a length around with it.  Neither does a `char *` for that matter, but by convention it ends with a `nul` byte which allows the length to be calculated (by, e.g., `strlen`).

Comment: I am carrying the length of the data elsewhere (I erased what the method had earlier as I was trying to debug why it wasnt working as exepected). Say I have an 4 byte integer. Can I cast it to a char pointer and get 4 chars corresponding to the bytes of the integer using that char pointer?

Comment: That should be a new question, which should include an attempt at coding it yourself.  Trying to answer it here will just complicate things.

Comment: Alright. I am still not quite sure why no error was thrown when the code executed. It just seemingly magically exited 0 upon that cast. Is there a way to capture this exception or is that normal?

Comment: IDK, it depends what was in `v`.  Was it zero?

Comment: Probally should have pointed this out, but _put is called from the method "m.write<short>(2)" above. So its a short with value 2

Comment: In that case I would expect a segfault, which is usually reported to the terminal / console.  Perhaps it isn't, under cygwin.  I don't use it so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Alright. Thank you I believe this answers my question. I suppose c++ checks char pointers to make sure they are a valid string. The code works fine when casting to other data types like short pointer so I guess that the code is exiting when it cant find that null byte or whatnot that you were talking about about

Comment: Actually, in this case, it's aborting when it tries to dereference an invalid pointer.  Casting to, e.g., a `short` doesn't dereference anything so the problem doesn't arise.  But a missing `nul` terminating byte can certainly cause similar problems, yes.

Comment: Solved. Rather then trying to cast the data to a pointer, it was better to cast my char array buffer pointer (with the index applied) to the data type pointer which I can then easily set the pointer of that to be equal to v. Thanks for the help @Paul Sanders